# Unity 5.0 TouchScript Pan with Oculus Plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hey guys I'm new to stackoverflow and was hoping anyone out there can help me with this problem :(

I'm using unity 5.1.1f personal and I'm trying to move 3d objects with the touchscript plugin. I'm also using the oculus and leapmotion plugins. For some reason the blue tag that's suppose to detect touch only appears behind the oculus lens views when I run the game as if they're not even in the game world to begin with. I suspect it might be a hierarchy issue but am at lost on how to solve it. I'm also confused about the touchscript plugin's synchronicity with the fiducial markers i plan to use to track the virtual objects positioning. If anyone out there can give me some help i'd greatly appreciate it!  I'm not very good with unity so i'm in a pickle of what I can do.... ;_;

Comment: Welcome! Can you post the code where you think the problem is?

Comment: Thank you for replying! ^^ I don't know where the code is because many of touchscripts's scripts aren't being recognized in monodevlop. But I am greeted with touchscript's child game object's  options in the inspector: MouseInput and Tuio Input show up

Comment: I meant your code, but having done some research, it looks like Unity is more GUI-based. Perhaps you could list some of the steps you've followed? Have you gotten the plugins to work individually? Obviously, I'm unlikely to be able to help you with your problem -- I'm just trying to elicit enough information so that someone more knowledgeable will be able to spot the problem quickly.

Comment: I followed this tutorial: https://github.com/TouchScript/TouchScript/wiki/Tutorial.-Dragging-3D-Objects-Around. (C&P to get the exact page...it doesn't take you to the full link when you click on it) It should give you a gist of what i'm trying to do but I guess my main problem is why the touch gesture appears behind the entire game scene and not in the game itself I can interact with the game object and thus move the cube via TUIO. But thanks so much for looking into this :)